# C# picturebox load image with an offset

Tags: c#, winforms, image, sprite, picturebox

I have a resource file (in .png format) which contain several images. They are sized and spaced in a way to where they should be relatively easy to call based on their offsets.

I can size the picturebox to fit one image just fine; however, I don't know how to load the image based on its offsets, so I will always just get the one in the top left.

I'm really fine with using just about any method, but haven't been able to turn up with anything useful in my searches -- since I didn't really know what to search for exactly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming your PNG image is *imgwidth* pixel wide and composed by *n* horizontal images, you could try this:

```
Image imgsrc = Image.FromFile("...."); // your PNG file
Image imgdst = new Bitmap(imgwidth/n, imgsrc.Height);
using (Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(imgdst))
{
    gr.DrawImage(imgsrc,
        new RectangleF(0, 0, imgdst.Width, imgdst.Height),
        new RectangleF(imgindex * imgwidth/n, 0, imgwidth/n, imgsrc.Height),
        GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
}
```

The idea is to create a new image (imgdst) and draw on it the part of original image you need.
With new image you can do what you please, even draw it in a picturebox.

Answer (score 9):

You can put the `PictureBox` in a `Panel`, using the panel as your viewport.  Make sure the panel's `AutoScroll` property is `false` so you don't get scroll bars appearing.  Then, load the image in the `PictureBox`, and set it's location relative to the `Panel` so only the area you'd like to show is visible.

```
pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.AutoSize;
pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(@"C:\MyPicture.png");
pictureBox1.Location = new Point(-100, -100);
```

Comment: My first idea was to store the original image and create a copy but this is way better, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're tring to do something like sprites; where you have just one image loaded and then move the "view port" around to show different images.

If that's the case, you won't be able to do this with the stock `PictureBox` class.  You can control the sizing, but not the positioning.  I think what you'd have to do is load the image, via code, and create new images based off the necessary portion of that image (using GDI+).

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to show a image for users, you could add the image into a label, then set the  alignment property of image as you like.