# Animation using List<Image>

Tags: c#, .net, animation

I'm skeptical if I'm doing this the right way.

I have to play an animation at about 60fps. I'm using a `List<Image>` to load all the frames at the time of initialization. And then using a `System.Timers.Timer` to call an event at every **10ms** which will change the image in the `pictureBox`.

```
List<Image> imageList = new List<Image>();

private static Timer_Event(o, e)
{
    pictureBox.Image = imageList[i++];
}
```

So, am I doing this right? Is there a better approach?

Comment: You'd probably have a better visual experience if you used a video file rather than a list of images.

Comment: There must be something better than that...any possibility of using .gif files?

Comment: @AdilMughal, I had that in mind, but aren't they lossy?

Comment: Yes, but at any speed above about 10 frames per second, you won't generally notice moderate video compression.  You can also strike the correct balance between compression and video fidelity.

Comment: @Sean AFAIK, GIF files are *not* lossy.  However, last I heard, the GIF format was patent-encumbered.  JPEG is AFAIK not patent-encumbered but it *is* lossy.

Comment: I'm using `PNGs`. I thought `GIFs` have a limited color range support, but I guess I'll try it. @David

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're describing seems unlikely to work in a robust fashion.  Here's a brief summary:

- In my experience, timers aren't generally accurate.  Since timer messages go through the Windows Message pump, they can only move as fast as your Windows UI processes messages.  Any application that interferes with messages will cause your timers to stutter, although careful work can prevent most of this.  Some classic discussion of timers here: [Winforms Timer for Dummies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1174733/winforms-timer-for-dummies)
- In general, List is a very inefficient way to store images.  For a one-second animation at 60 frames per second, you will have to hold 60 images in memory and decompress each one individually.

Here are some possible solutions, and the tradeoffs they entail:

**Full Motion Video**

If you are looking to present a full motion video on your form, you should really consider using a `MediaElement` (for WPF applications: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/dpatra/media-element-in-wpf/ ) or a `MediaPlayer` object (for WinForms applications: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383953(v=vs.90).aspx ).

This will allow you to play a lengthy video that contains extremely high quality images, varied compression, and start or stop the playback arbitrarily.  However, the startup and memory usage requirements of a full video player are greater than just displaying a single image on screen.  You will find that your application takes a moment to initialize the video subsystem, which may be annoying.

**Animated Images**

It's possible to show an animated image in a picturebox in Windows Forms or WPF.  You would simply generate the animated image - generally using a GIF animation file.  This will work smoothly for a majority of simple animations, and it's possible to get free-to-use animated GIFs from websites like this one:  http://www.chimply.com/Generator

Here's a walkthrough of how to place an animated GIF on your form: http://trompelecode.com/2010/12/animated-progress-indicator-in-csharp-windows-forms/

**Sprite Animation**

Let's say you need to accurately represent each image exactly (which isn't necessary if you're simply trying to look appealing), and that you don't want the overhead of a video system (which is okay if you're only playing a second or two worth of animations).  What you want to do then is create a single composite "sprite" image.  This reduces the memory overhead requirements of your application and reduces the amount of time decompressing files.

For example, here's a website that generates PNG sprites for you: http://wearekiss.com/spritepad

Once you generate an image with sprites, you can place it within a picturebox and animate the image by changing the relative position of the image within the picturebox.  Here's a walkthrough of how to accomplish this: [C# picturebox load image with an offset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7680313/c-sharp-picturebox-load-image-with-an-offset)

**Summary**

Any way you choose to display an animated image, you will have some tradeoffs.  I like to pick the simplest possible solution for myself - and in my case I like to use an animated GIF image.  Good luck animating!

Comment: The results with using a `Timer` are quite smooth. Can you broaden more about the `AVI` part. How can I incorporate an `AVI` into my `Form`?

Comment: It seems like you're writing a WinForms application - if so, you can deposit a Windows Media Player element - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383953.aspx . If you're using WPF, you can use `MediaElement`.  But are you just trying to play a nice smooth animation to show that your form is doing work?  Like an "in progress" indicator?

Comment: This might be what you want:  http://trompelecode.com/2010/12/animated-progress-indicator-in-csharp-windows-forms/

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for, but thanx. :) @TedSpence

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you're looking for?  FYI, it's possible to build an animated GIF in completely lossless form - for example, this guy's site produces animated gifs without artifacts: http://www.chimply.com/Generator#classic-spinner

Comment: I was looking for a better choice. There are about 166 `png` frames I have, with an average of about 5KB. The animation is pretty complicated to be handled by `GIF`, it's not just a rotating circle, it's more like Window's Copy/Move dialog animations. Any-who, I'm marking this as an answer, because it's deep. @TedSpence

Comment: lol..I marked it as an answer before you edited it. +1 for more thought sharing. :) @TedSpence

Answer (score 0):

**The .avi is alternative** otherwise, however, if you have bunch of images than probably utilizing threads/timers apparently seems to be the way forward.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to use an animated gif in that pictureBox and don't mess with timers.

Comment: Depends what kind of video you're compressing - GIF doesn't have to be lossy :)

Answer (score 0):

You may also be able to put your animation together using [WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752312.aspx) or Silverlight  ... if you need the animation to be interactive or programmatically controllable that would probably be the way to go.

If on the other hand the animated content is static then AVI (or MPEG etc.) is probably your best bet.

You don't say exactly what you're trying to accomplish so I can't be sure.

Comment: Why is `AVI` better? Isn't `AVI` too a bunch of Images? @David

Comment: Yes, the frames in an AVI video are still images.  But a video file format will also support sound, and may have built-in compression which you would get "for free".  But IMHO the real kicker is that a video player will almost certainly unload at least some of the frames (images) that have already been rendered (some of the frames may be cached to help performance), plus you can almost always start playing the animation before the entire file has loaded ... bottom line _you don't have to have all the images in memory at once_.

Comment: There are about 166 images with an average of about 5KB each. I think you are right, I should use an `AVI`,  but don't you think the overhead of including an `AVI`renderer would be much greater? @David

Comment: @Sean Those are pretty small, so in this case maybe.  You have to weigh that against the cost of maintenance if & when the set of images changes, plus the cost of maintaining the rendering code.