# Moving a bitmap smoothly in a picturebox (a la google maps)

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation, picturebox

I have a Bitmap loaded in a picturebox. My problem is that I want it to move smoothly when using a mouse. Is there some super-duper function for moving and image by some pixels very fast?

Or do I have to repaint a picturebox completely every time I move by a single pixel (somehow with a LockBits method)?

I need it to run fast with no flickering.

Comment: Can you post some of the code that's NOT giving you the results that you want?

Answer (score 2):

Obviously you have to redraw the whole box every time you move, the trick is that you don't recalculate the whole area you see, you keep the whole (or at least a large chunk) of the picture loaded, and just specify wich part to draw.

Comment: is there a fuction in C# that draws that part of a bitmap (with given starting points) in a picturebox?

Comment: @Novellizator: [DrawImage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.drawimage.aspx)?

Answer (score 0):

An interesting concept is described here, and it might work for your needs - assumes your bitmap is not tiled, i.e. can be loaded all at once:

[Put the PictureBox in a Panel, using the panel as your viewport.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7680598/897326)