# return a rectangular part of a Bitmap by reference in WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms

When I have a huge Bitmap - can I somehow return a rectangular part of it by reference? Without the need of copying the content?

Guys, let me emphasize I'm doing it in WinForms - can I do something even there?

NOTE: I have asked the same question few weeks ago, but it was closed as duplicate. HOWEVER it was because the moderators thought I ask for a solution in WPF - but I ask about WinForms!
Thanks.

Comment: Does this sort of thing help, or am I misunderstanding the question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7680313/c-sharp-picturebox-load-image-with-an-offset

Comment: Bitmap.Clone() gives you a very cheap bitmap that references the original bitmap's pixel data.

Comment: @HansPassant are you sure that it just references the original Bitmap? because that is the way I do it and it consumes enormous memory... (https://github.com/novellizator/path-planner/blob/master/TomyMaps/TomyMaps/Map.cs line 288)